# Make absolutely positioned div the height of the parent container

Tags: html, css

How to make red div to equal in height a parent yellow div?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.left {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
}

.right {
  background-color: orangered;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/fafexulube/edit?html,css,output

**Update**: the height of the left div cannot be changed, it's got 2000px to show it's higher than its parent.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you absolutely positioning everything? Otherwise you can consider the various solutions, using table cells, flex box and the likes.

Comment: it comes with the territory... If there's no obvious solution, then I will likely go with the table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `position` on the parent to something other than `static`, you can use `height:100%;` or `top:0; bottom:0;` on the child.

If you want a sibling to define the height of the parent, you can not set it to `position:absolute;`.

Take a look at this updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qavihuleme/3/edit.

Specifically, add `position:relative;` to the parent and remove `position:absolute;` from the sibling (`.left`).

Comment: you've changed the problem when you set height on the parent and made child divs the height of the parent. In initial problem, the height is driven by the left div.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/cacopejabe/1/

Make div sizes match... The yellow div is container thus you need to make other two divs same size... I took out 2000px height on left... You can choose to put 2000px height on black (your red).

Comment: the size of both left and right divs is determined by their content which is generated dynamically. what you suggest might not work because of this

Comment: You have styling of "height: 2000px;" on ".left" that is what is causing the mismatch.. Your comment does not match the code you submitted...

Comment: 2000px in my example is a simplification, meaning there's some content of that height. This height makes the parent adjust, but not the right div. As I see it, comment matches the code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wish I can help you but out of my league. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is with position absolute on everything, it's messing the layout, you should really use floats or if you don't care for older browsers, flexbox. This is deep down and dirty js/jquery solution xD:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var height = $('.left').css('height');
  $('.right').css('height', height);
});
```

Comment: nice hack for desperate times :)